# Understanding Haskell expression evaluation

Tags: haskell, expression, evaluation

I need help understanding Haskell expression evaluation. Take for example:

```
group . sort $ [1,2,3]
```

This is my idea of how the expression is evaluated, am I totally wrong?
1. . is evaluated first, this creates the function Ord a => [a] -> [[a]]
2. $ is evaluated, this evaluates the right side of $
3. The right side of $ is fed as a parameter to the function on the left side of $

How do spaces (highest precedence?) tie in all to this?

Comment: There are no spaces here, not ones with precedence, anyway.

Comment: @Karolis, I think the poster means function application.

Comment: The order of evaluation is exactly the same as in `2 + 3 * 4`.

Comment: @PaulJohnson, I know, as I said, there is no normal application in that line. Just $ and .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The expression tree has `($)` at the top, with `(group . sort)` and `[1,2,3]` as children.  I can see this since `(.)` has a higher priority # of 9 and binds more tightly than `($)` with priority 0:

```
Prelude> :i (.)
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c   -- Defined in `GHC.Base'
infixr 9 .

Prelude> :i ($)
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b   -- Defined in `GHC.Base'
infixr 0 $
```

The `(group . sort)` has `(.)` as the top and `group` and `sort` as parameters.  The `[1,2,3]` desugars to `(1:(2:(3:([]))))`.  This is the parsed expression tree.

It is evaluated by forcing the `(group . sort)`, to get a function, and then passing `[1,2,3]` unevaluated to this function.

`(group . sort)` is `\xs -> group (sort xs)` and so this becomes `group (sort [1,2,3])`.  `group` looks at the outmost constructor of `(sort [1,2,3])` which forces `(sort [1,2,3])` to produce `(1 :  thunk)` where `thunk` will eventually be evaluated to `[2,3]`.